# Shiro authentication redirect not working for *.html

Tags: java, html, jsp, google-chrome, shiro

My shiro.ini config file

```
[main]

shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.successUrl = /secure/index.html
logout.redirectUrl = /logout.jsp


# redirect to an error page if user does not have access rights
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.html

# configure Shiro's default 'ssl' filter to be disabled while testing:
ssl.enabled = false

[users]
user1 = user1, user

[urls]
/resources/** = anon
/partials/** = anon
/logout = logout
/login.jsp = authc
/secure/** = authc
/account/** = authc
/api/** = anon
/** = anon
```

Accessing /account/index.jsp is redirected to /login.jsp
Accessing /secure/favicon.png is redirected to /login.jsp
Accessing /secure/index.html displays the index.html, even though the user isn't logged in.

I presume, that Shiro is somehow configured to secure resources that are *.jsp, *.png and not *.html?

---

On further debugging, this seems to be a Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m and Firefox 30 specific problem. I presume Chrome might be caching the page. Internet Explorer 11 correctly redirects to login.jsp when /secure/index.html is requested.

Clearing Chrome's cache is one way to fix this. Any ideas on a permanent solution? I wouldn't want users to be able to directly access the secure site due to cached files.

Further analysis: Accessing /secure/index.html changes the url to /secure/ with the index.html page shown. However, if you view page source, it is /login.jsp

So the /secure/index.html page is shown even though the underlying html is /login.jsp i.e. correctly redirected by Shiro.